# number of solutions to N-queens problem in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, backtracking

I'm trying to implement the pseudo code below but instead of the solutions to N-queens, I want to print out the numbers of solutions to N-queens problem where 1 <= n <= 12. However, my outputs don't match the correct outputs. Could you guys help me to find where I did wrong in my code?

P.S.
the pseudo code from the textbook use C++ but my code is in Java.

*update:* After printing out the first six n-queens solutions (as Ole V.V. suggested, thanks!), I found that the problem in my code is that some solutions were found twice, thus the counts of them got counted twice. Still trying to come up with a solution to this problem

*update 2:* I've found the problem in my code and indicated where it was. Lots of thanks for the help.

```
The pseudo code:

Inputs: positive integer *n*.
Outputs: all possible ways *n* queens can be placed on an *n x n* chessboard so that no two queens threaten each other. Each output consists of an array of integers *col* indexed from 1 to n, where *col[i]* is the column where the queen in the *i*th row is placed.

void queens (index i) {
    index j;

    if ( promising(i) ) {
        if ( i == n ) {
            cout << col[1] through col[n];
        } else {
            for ( j = 1; j <= n; j++) {
            col[i + 1] = j;
            queens(i + 1);
            }
        }
    }
}
bool promising (index i) {
    index k;
    bool switch;

    k = 1;
    switch = true;
    while ( k < i && switch ) {
        if ( col[i] == col[k] || abs(col[i] - col[k]) == i-k ) {
            switch = false;
        }
        k++;
    }
    return switch;
}
```

and here is my code:

```
class Queens {
    public static int n = 1, count = 0;
    public static int[] col;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = 0;
        while (n <= 12) {
            col = new int[n + 1];
            while (index <= n) { // just use the function once for each n
                queens(index); // i.e. just use queens(0);
                index++;
            }
            System.out.println("n = " + n + " # of solution(s) = " + count);
            count = 0;
            index = 0;
            n++;
        }
    }

    public static void queens(int i) {
        int index;
        if (promising(i)) {
            if (i == n) {
                count++;
            } else {
                for (index = 1; index <= n; index++) {
                    col[i + 1] = index;
                    queens(i + 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static boolean promising(int i) {
        int index;
        boolean _switch;

        index = 1;
        _switch = true;
        while (index < i && _switch) {
            if (col[i] == col[index] || Math.abs(col[i] - col[index]) == (i - index)) {
                _switch = false;
            }
            index++;
        }
        return _switch;
    }
}
```

and below is the outputs I got from my codes and the correct outputs:

```
My outputs:
n = 1 # of solution(s) = 2
n = 2 # of solution(s) = 0
n = 3 # of solution(s) = 0
n = 4 # of solution(s) = 2
n = 5 # of solution(s) = 12
n = 6 # of solution(s) = 4
n = 7 # of solution(s) = 44
n = 8 # of solution(s) = 96
n = 9 # of solution(s) = 380
n = 10 # of solution(s) = 788
n = 11 # of solution(s) = 2776
n = 12 # of solution(s) = 14700

the correct outputs:
n=1 # of solutions = 1
n=2 # of solutions = 0
n=3 # of solutions = 0
n=4 # of solutions = 2
n=5 # of solutions = 10
n=6 # of solutions = 4
n=7 # of solutions = 40
n=8 # of solutions = 92
n=9 # of solutions = 352
n=10 # of solutions = 724
n=11 # of solutions = 2680
n=12 # of solutions = 14200
```

The first six solutions:

```
1 
1 // counted twice!
n = 1 # of solution(s) = 2
n = 2 # of solution(s) = 0
n = 3 # of solution(s) = 0
2 4 1 3
3 1 4 2
n = 4 # of solution(s) = 2
1 3 5 2 4
1 4 2 5 3
2 4 1 3 5
2 5 3 1 4 
3 1 4 2 5
3 5 2 4 1
4 1 3 5 2
4 2 5 3 1
5 2 4 1 3 //
5 3 1 4 2 //
5 2 4 1 3 // counted twice!
5 3 1 4 2 // counted twice!
n = 5 # of solution(s) = 12
2 4 6 1 3 5
3 6 2 5 1 4
4 1 5 2 6 3
5 3 1 6 4 2
n = 6 # of solution(s) = 4
```

Comment: How are symmetries counted? When one solution can be obtained by turning or reflecting another solution, do they count as 1 or 2 solutions?

Comment: If you modify your program to print out the 12 solutions for n = 5, you can probably see which 2 of them are not solutions.

Comment: @OleV.V. Symmetries are counted separately. My code is in Java. Just the pseudo code from the textbook is in C++. I'll try the method you mentioned and see if I can make it right. Thanks!